# What does the inverted V represent in math

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I know that A V B represents Logical disjunction which means A OR B and the result of it is false only when both A and B are false . But I still didn't understand what an inverted V means as shown in the image below. I know that cij , ail and blj are cells in a matrix but I dont understand the meaning on the whole. Can someone please help.

[image]

Comment: `\land` gives $\land$, and is short for "logical and". In the context of logic, $\land$ is the conjunction. It can also denote other things in other contexts (wedge products, exterior products, for example).

Comment: It is quite common to write $a\wedge b$ for the minimum of two real numbers $a$ and $b$, and $a\vee b$ for the maximum. These interpretations agree, of course, with the interpretations as “logical and” and “logical or” when $1$ is used to stand for truth and $0$ for falsehood. Even more generally, you come across these symbols, with similar interpretation in lattices, where $a\wedge b$ is the greatest element smaller or equal to both $a$ abd $b$, for example.

Comment: Where have you found it? Are this $a_{i,l}$ boolens, numbers or what?

Answer (score 2):

It is very common for $\wedge$ to be used when one considers differential $k$-forms. This is not it, though. It's logical AND.

Answer (score 0):

For your context I think Conjunction or AND